# ¿Cómo revisar todas las id de los elementos en esta función? jquery

Tags: jquery

Siempre que entro a esta función y encuentra el id(1) no continua revisando si hay mas elementos con el id 3 y 5. ¿Cómo lo soluciono?

En la etiqueta a suelen solo listarse a veces las id 1,3 y 5. unas veces solo está el 3 u otras el 1 y 5 o el 5 solo.. varia.

```
                <ul class="dropdown-menu alert-dropdown"  onclick="javascript:cambia_enlace();">
                    <li ng-repeat="datalist in Notificaciones" >
                        <a id="{{datalist.ID_NOTIFICACIONES}}" href="">
                            <div>{{ datalist.TEXTO_NOTIFICACION }}</div>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>


        function cambia_enlace() {
            var id = document.getElementById('1')
            if (id == null) {
                var id2 = document.getElementById('3');
                if (id2 == null) {
                    var id3 = document.getElementById('5');
                    if (id3 == null) {
                    } else {
                        id3.href = "Principal.html#/Pago";
                    }
                } else {
                    id2.href = "Principal.html#/Abono";
                }
            } else {
                id.href = "Principal.html#/Inventario";
            }
        }
```

Comment: ¿Que es exactamente el 'elemento'?

Comment: @Lithorell mira arriba lo que hize y asi funciona, pero hay un problema..

Comment: No tenemos la bola de cristal para adivinar cual es el problema si no lo explicas ;)

Comment: @Lithorell ya lo modifiqué.. :v perdón

Comment: Porque le estas diciendo que si la primera id no es null no siga adelante. Es decir, si la uno no existe va a ir a buscarte la 3 o la 5. Y asi sucesivamente.

Comment: @GDP ¿de qué otra manera se puede poner?

Comment: @GDP la primera parte de tu respuesta es correcta, la segunda creo que te sobra un no ;)

Comment: @Lithorell gracias, me he liado entre tanto null :P.

Comment: @RubxnMC ¿que es exactamente lo que quieres hacer?

Comment: @Lithorell si la etiqueta tiene el id 1 hacer que esta me lleve a la vista de inventario, si la otra etiqueta tiene el id 3 que me lleve a abono y si hay otra etiqueta con el id 5 que me deje en la vista de pago

Comment: @Lithorell solo existen esas tres id, y varian, ya que dependen de el estado de una consulta interna. Es decir, a veces solo está la etiqueta con el id 5 y las demás no. O esta solo la etiqueta id 1 y 5 pero la 3 no. y así sucesivamente.

Comment: Muestranos el HTML porque si no la respuesta es amplisima

Comment: @Lithorell listo.

Comment: Me da que tu problema viene porque se esta lanzando antes el evento del enlace que tu funcion.

Comment: @Lithorell Pero igual funciona, solo cuando hay una sola id. Cuando tengo dos etiquetas por ejemplo el 1 y 5, cuando le doy clic a la etiqueta que tiene la id 5 me manda para la vista de la tiqueta 1 y está mal.

Comment: Pero es que eso es normal, cuando haces click revisa si esta la 1 y como esta usa esta. La funcion tienes que hacerla a nivel de enlace no a nivel de `ul`

Comment: Eso era, gracias @Lithorell me haz salvado. si quieres ponlo como respuesta para darte reputación!

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero, si la id es variable, no puedes buscar al elemento por ella. Yo te recomiendo variar la clase y mantener la id.
De esta manera, podras buscar al elemento con facilidad. Una vez que lo tengas seleccionas su clase y la metes en un `switch` con un case por cada opcion.

He metido un html y una funcion inicializando para que sea mas comprensible y asi ejecutarlo.

```js
function cambia_link(){
  
  var ida= "avariable";
  var elemento = document.getElementById(ida);
  var class_elemento = elemento.className;
  
  switch(class_elemento){
    case "a1":  
    elemento.href= "https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript";
    break;
    case "a2":
    elemento.href= "https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php";
    break;
    case "a3":
    elemento.href= "https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html";
    break;
  }
}

(function(){
cambia_link();
})();
```

```html
<a id="avariable" class="a3" href="#"> Anchor variable</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ya que como etiqueta has puesto `jquery`, una posible solución usando `jquery` y no `javascript`podría ser:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu alert-dropdown">
     <li ng-repeat="datalist in Notificaciones" >
          <a id="{{datalist.ID_NOTIFICACIONES}}" class="enlace" href="">
               <div>{{ datalist.TEXTO_NOTIFICACION }}</div>
          </a>
     </li>
</ul>
```

La parte de `jquery`sería esta

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".class").click(function(){
      var id= parseInt($(this).attr('id'));

      switch(id){
        case 1:  
          $(this).attr('href','Principal.html#/Inventario');
          break;
        case 2:
          $(this).attr('href','Principal.html#/Abono');
          break;
        case 3:
          $(this).attr('href','Principal.html#/Pago');
          break;
        default:
          $(this).attr('href','Principal.html#/Inventario');
          break;
      }
  });
)}
```